# In Rails how do I change the params of a controller method using a search form tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I'm building a Rails app that interacts with an external search API. I have a class method with the search functionality which is accessed by my index method in my design controller. How can I make it so that my form search changes the params of my controller method and thus performs a search? My code is below. Would appreciate the help :)

Class method:

```
class Api
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "http://search.exampleapi.com"

  attr_accessor :name

  # Find a particular design, based on its name
  def find(name)
    self.class.get("/designs", query: { q: name }).parsed_response
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class DesignsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @search = Api.new.find(params[:q])['results']
    end
end
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'designs#index'
    resources :designs
end
```

View:

```
<h1>Search</h1>

<%= form_tag(controller: "designs", action: "search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>

<h2>Search results:</h2>

<% @search.each do |design| %>  
<h3><%= design['name'] %></h3>
<h5><%= design['thumbnail_url'] %></h5>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you should change `action: "search"` to `action: "index"`

Comment: Thanks :) I'm getting a `No route matches [POST] "/"` when i try and search though.

Comment: Just a couple things I would point out semi-unrelated to the question - in Rails land we would call controller methods 'actions' instead of methods. At least the ones that are accessed via some HTTP request like index, show, create, etc. This seems to be the source of the problem as kasperite pointed out. Private methods would still be called methods. Also, it's unlikely that you need to use `include HTTParty` in a Rails app - it should be done for you already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you using index page you can do, designs_path will automatically route you to index controller

```
<%= form_tag(designs_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```